# Is it possible to run GoogleTest - based unit-tests with Hexagon SDK?

Tags: googletest, hexagon-dsp

I'm very new to the topic of DSP development. I have asked this question in the Qualcomm forum 2 months ago, but haven't received any answer.

Currently I'm involved in the porting of parts of our code to the Hexagon DSP, made by Qualcomm.

Our code base compiles to a shared library and a unit-test suite based on GoogleTest.

I have successfully compiled the library with hexagon-clang, that is a part of Hexagon SDK 3.5.2. However, hexagon-clang doesn't compile gtest, because of limited standard library support.

What options do I have to run unit-tests?

*Update*.

1. Our code is configured with CMake. It uses `Hexagon_toolchain.cmake`, coming with SDK. Related CMake command line switches are: `-DV=hexagon_Debug_toolv83_v66  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT%\build\cmake\Hexagon_Toolchain.cmake -DQURT_OS=1 -DHEXAGON_CMAKE_ROOT=%HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT%\build\cmake`
2. During compilation of GTest hexagon-clang cannot find header file `regex.h`. Indeed, this file can be found only in Android NDK, that is installed by Hexagon SDK. I've tried setting include paths for hexagon-clang, but have got other errors with other header files. I've stopped this exercise because I doubt that "cherry-picking" fragments of Android NDK is a correct way to build an application that should run on DSP.

Comment: "However, hexagon-clang doesn't compile gtest, because of limited standard library support."

How does this fail?

Comment: It cannot find header file `regex.h`.

Comment: Your profile says that you work at Qualcomm. Could you point me to some beginners' tutorial? I'm missing some basic information about how things work and having hard time to find it through 7K pages of PDF files. For example, what is `runelf.pbn`, and why can't I run some apps without it? What makes an app standalone? Can I create standalone app linked to `dspCV` and `rpcmem` libs? Why is `argv` in `main` equal NULL?  Official forums in QDN seem to be dead.

Comment: Hexagon SDK does not provide a library with posix regex.  Try building with `GTEST_USES_POSIX_RE` disabled.

Comment: adding `-DGTEST_HAS_POSIX_RE=0` has helped with this error. However, now it cannot find `rmdir`, `chdir`, `mkdir`, `STDOUT_FILENO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

1. Turned off two GTest options (`GTEST_HAS_POSIX_RE` and `GTEST_HAS_STREAM_REDIRECTION`):

```
    ...
    if(HEXAGON)
        add_compile_definitions(GTEST_HAS_POSIX_RE=0 GTEST_HAS_STREAM_REDIRECTION=0)
    endif()

    add_subdirectory(gtest)
    ....
```

2. Added some code to GoogleTest to support QURT. Unfortunately, I cannot publish these changes, however, they are straightforward. GoogleTest library contains an OS abstraction layer, which was missing QURT support. I've just followed error messages from the compiler and added missing functions.
   During that exercise I've found following 3 issues:

- `getcwd` function in QURT POSIX support library always returned empty string.
- there was no `write` function in QURT, so I've simulated it using `fwrite` (funny that `read` was present).
- `argv` in `main` was always `NULL`, and I've had to call overloaded `InitGoogleTest()`.